# How to pass data bettween IE browser to Dot NET web browser Control

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, browser, webbrowser-control

I have opened the IE browser from DOT NET web browser control. But I could not transfer data bettween both. Can any one tell how to pass the data bettween IE browser control to DOT NET web browser control and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

How to set html from c#(data from c# to WebBrowser):

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Navigate("about:blank");
browser.Document.Write("<html><body>...</body></html>");
```

You can get control on c# by using the events of WebBrowser (get control from webBrowser to c#):
http://www.dotnetperls.com/webbrowser

Comment: The problem is that I dont have static HTML content. Also there is a need to call a method in .NET from IE browser. Detailed description will be really helpful as I am new to .NET

Comment: Please be more specific, tell me what you want to do, and I or others will tell you how to do it if we know.

Comment: I have a browser control with a button. When i click on that button, i open IE using window.open() . i want to call a javascript function available in web browser from IE. I tried using window.opener.functionName but it does not work.